# Tapestry5 application not running on WTP Tomcat server

Tags: maven-2, tomcat, tapestry, eclipse-wtp

My Tapestry 5 application is running fine with a maven "tomcat:run" build, but not when I use a Tomcat WTP server.

I.E: I created a tapestry 5 project based on the tapestry 5 quickstart maven archetype. At the beginning, it works fine with both servers.

After playing a little bit with the dependencies (i.e. adding and then removing the exact same libraries), I get a 404 error on each of my pages when I start the WTP server, while the project is correctly running with a maven "tomcat:run".

I tried to clean up everything, rebuild from scratch... but so far nothing.

What could explain such a behaviour? 
Where should I look for fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: "Where should I look for fixing this?" -- Look at the logs.

Comment: Unfortunately, logs aren't much helpful here. I was implying, do you have any idea of what could cause that behaviour? Like a difference between WTP and maven embedded servers etc.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If yes, I would really appreciate a solution. I am facing exact the same problem...

Comment: I guess I solved it but can't remember what the actual problem was. From one of my comment below, you should compare both classpathes and see if there's any difference. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn-on all logs in the tomcat: conf/logging.properties, add line org.apache.catalina.level=FINEST

Comment: thank you me_delete, the problem actually came from a difference between both classpathes...